# Image slider with random effect

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to effect any images of slider randomly, but none of two consecutive images get the same effects at the same time. How can I do that?

```js
$(window).load(function() {
  $('#slider').nivoSlider();
});
$('#slider').nivoSlider({
  effect: 'random',
  slices: 4,
  boxCols: 8,
  boxRows: 4,
  startSlide: 0,
  manualAdvance: false,
  randomStart: false,
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-nivoslider/3.2/jquery.nivo.slider.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-nivoslider/3.2/nivo-slider.css" />

<div id="wrapper">
  <div class="slider-wrapper theme-default">
    <div id="slider" class="nivoSlider">
      <img src="https://www.gettyimages.ie/gi-resources/images/Homepage/Hero/UK/CMS_Creative_164657191_Kingfisher.jpg" data-thumb="images/toystory.jpg" alt="" />
      <a href="http://dev7studios.com"><img src="http://wowslider.com/sliders/demo-81/data1/images/redkite50498.jpg" data-thumb="images/up.jpg" alt="" title="This is an example of a caption" /></a>
      <img src="http://ec.europa.eu/research/headlines/news/images/11_12_17_small.jpg" data-thumb="images/walle.jpg" alt="" />
      <img src="https://secure.i.telegraph.co.uk/multimedia/archive/03597/POTD_chick_3597497k.jpg" data-thumb="images/nemo.jpg" alt="" title="#htmlcaption" />
    </div>
    <div id="htmlcaption" class="nivo-html-caption">
      <strong>This</strong> is an example of a <em>HTML</em> caption with <a href="#">a link</a>.
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="htmlcaption" class="nivo-html-caption">
    <strong>This</strong> is an example of a <em>HTML</em> caption with <a href="#">a link</a>.
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [documentation](https://docs.themeisle.com/article/487-nivo-slider-settings), the following animations are available for use:

- sliceDown
- sliceDownLeft
- sliceUp
- sliceUpLeft
- sliceUpDown
- sliceUpDownLeft
- fold
- fade
- random
- slideInRight
- slideInLeft
- boxRandom
- boxRain
- boxRainReverse
- boxRainGrow
- boxRainGrowReverse

You are able to set the animation for each transition by using the `data-transition`, as shown [here](https://docs.themeisle.com/article/490-custom-transitions-per-slide). With all of this in mind, you could override the `beforeChange: function(){}` function to set the new value for the `data-transition` property, excluding the animation names listed above which are referenced by the slide that is currently being shown.

Comment: thank you for answering my question , but can you give me an example ?